# Does not load the secure cdn link in browserstack

Tags: cdn, browserstack

We got the following issue while using the below CDN links in browser stack.

Please find the configuration below Android 4.4 and Chrome 63. However the same CDN link is working properly while checking in Tab with the same configuration. Is there any configuration we need to do in our side?